# Can’t find element after Google smart lock

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I've met some unexpected behavior while trying to automate login in my Android app.
Appium 1.7.1

Scenario:

Launch App
Click login button (by id)
here google smart lock window appears
click “cancel” on google smart lock (by id, “com.google.android.gms:id/cancel”)
trying to click “edit_userName” button, but now can’t find such element by id. And can’t find any element by id or text of my application which is on screen now.
If I connect device without google smart lock everything works perfect.

It seems like I'm loosing focus of my app.

Any thoughts how to handle this?

Comment: Is this a valid usecase for your automation? if not.. then not a problem

Comment: Yes, it's valid. I want to have opportunity to log in with different users.